# JDA 4.2 how to get all users that have a specific role?

Tags: discord, roles, discord-jda

I'm looking to receive all discord users from a guild that have a specific role.

Since `.getGuild().getMembersWithRoles([role]);` only search cached users I don't know how to do it.
Note, the discord server has multiple thousand users so caching everything would be bad.

I searched for something like: `JDABot.retrieveUserByRole([role]);` but didn't find anything.

JDA Version: `4.2.0_214-withDependencies`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `Guild#findMembers(Predicate)`

It'll look something like this:

```
List<Member> members = guild.findMembers(member -> {
    if (member.getRoles().contains(role)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}).get();
```

Read more about `Guild#findMembers(Predicate)` here: https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#findMembers(java.util.function.Predicate)